# List of excel files is read in as list of lists

Tags: r, list, csv, dataframe

I have a directory of 332 Excel files which I'm reading into R as follows:

```
list_files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/mslomka/Documents/R/Datasets/Week 2", pattern = ".csv")
read_files <- lapply(list_files, read.csv)
```

However, when I subset the `read_files` list, all the components are lists rather than data frames/matrices (which is what they should be, given that they are Excel files).

I would like to either (a) read all the excels in as data frame, or (b) create a loop that coerces each of the lists into a data frame.

I have tried several approaches for (b) but none have worked, for example `lapply(read_files, as.data.frame)`. I have only managed to coerce individual lists into data frames, for example by doing `as.data.frame(read_files[1])`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: They are data frames. Use `read_files[[1]]`

Answer (score 3):

Some useful infos [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the?rq=1) + this meaningful picture from [Twitter](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/643381054758363136)

[image]

Comment: I get it, but that doesn't seem like the right container to begin with. Who puts pepper packets in a pepper shaker?

Comment: Like @pfabri mentionned it `do.call(rbind,read_files)` will gather pepper packets but you'll lose some kind of information. If data is splitted in several files, I suppose there's a good reason. Maybe the wrapping contains infos like "black pepper", "green pepper", "pink pepper"... Lists forces you to use `lapply` and functions

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this gives you a list of lists:

```
read_files <- lapply(list_files, read.csv)
```

i.e. `read.files[[i]]` would return a list.

You have also managed to convert each of those `[[i]]` lists into dataframes by doing `lapply(read_files, as.data.frame)`.

Do you now want to create one dataframe which contains all the information from each of the dataframes contained in `read_files`? If so, this will do the job:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, read_files)
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Did you find this helpful?